# Stars in visual studio 2013

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to make a 6 pt star.
How do I go about getting the points?

```
    star = New Polygon
    star.Stroke = New SolidColorBrush(Yellow)
    star.Points.Add(New Point(0, 0))
    star.Points.Add(New Point(0, 0))
    star.Points.Add(New Point(0, 0))

    MyCanvas.Children.Add(star)
    star2 = New Polygon
    star2.Stroke = New SolidColorBrush(Yellow)
    star2.Points.Add(New Point(0, 0))
    star2.Points.Add(New Point(0, 0))
    star2.Points.Add(New Point(0, 0))

    MyCanvas.Children.Add(star2)
```

Comment: What language are you using? Visual Basic? Please add a tag for it. (Visual Studio is an editor; it is no more related to your question than notepad.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I got rid of a lot of unnecessary and distracting tags. When you say "how do I go about getting the points?", what do you mean? Do you want to fill the screen? Get the user to click (six times, a centre and inscribing radius)? User numeric input? Drag from a toolbar?